# How to add/update milestones in a feature?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rally

I am not able to add or update milestones filed for the Features in the Rally. If anyone having the code available using C# to update the same, please share with me. I am searching and doing from last one week with no luck.

Comment: Found this question about creating milestones [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855474/permissions-error-creating-rally-milestone-when-using-api-key) it might be helpful to you.

Comment: Pairing that information about milestones with the rallyRestApi.Update function [link](http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/5403697b-4d9b-0f1a-db4e-9ff4235ef29d.htm) might get you there. It would be useful if you shared what you have already attempted.

Comment: Thanks Jared. Tried but not solving my problem. Actually, I am searching an existing Feature in my Rally and want to update it. Currently, there is no milestone added in this particular Feature. So, i want to add a milestone. If i see Rally on the UI then I can select multiple values for Milestone combo box on the Rally UI. But not able to add it by code using Rally Rest API and C#.